# How to accelerate the convergence of a Power series?

Tags: taylor-expansion, power-series, convergence-acceleration

Is there a way to accelerate the convergence of alternating Taylor's series such as that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n x^n=A 
$$
approaches its value with less number of terms.

Since its an alternating series, I wondered if Euler's transformation might do the trick where
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(\Delta^n a)_0}{2^{2n+1}}
$$
Where
$$
(\Delta^n a)_0 = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} a_{n-k}
$$
If anyone knows any better way to accelerate the convergence of Taylor's series, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Inside the radius of convergence, Taylor series already converge exponentially. Are you thinking of a specific (type of) Taylor series at a specific point?

Comment: @GregMartin Well, I was thinking of just some general way of transforming the Taylor series into another one that would require fewer terms to achieve an equal approximation. Is it required for the Taylor series to be at a specific point to apply acceleration?

Comment: Note that in applying Euler's transformation to a power series $\sum_n (-1)^nb_nx^n$, the $a_n$ in the transformation is $b_nx^n$, not just $b_n$. Thus you would have to calculate a separate $(\Delta^na)_0$ for each value of $x$. I think you will find this significantly increases the amount of calculation, instead of decreasing it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, that is what I recently realized, I think I will be disregarding series acceleration for now, but thank you for confirming my thoughts.